# How to use MailKit with Google after May 30, 2022?

Tags: .net, gmail, imap, mailkit

Up to this point I was happily connecting to my Gmail account with a method similar to this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MimeMessage>> GetMessagesAsync()
{
    using var imapClient = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient();
    var secureSocketOptions = SecureSocketOptions.Auto;
    if (useSsl) secureSocketOptions = SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect;
    await imapClient.ConnectAsync(host, port, secureSocketOptions);

    await imapClient.AuthenticateAsync(login, password);

    await imapClient.Inbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    var uids = await imapClient.Inbox.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.All);

    var messages = new List<MimeMessage>();
    foreach (var uid in uids)
        messages.Add(await imapClient.Inbox.GetMessageAsync(uid));

    imapClient.Disconnect(true);

    return messages;
}
```

Since May 30, 2022, this is no longer possible as support for 'less secure apps' was [disabled](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en):

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

How do I use Mailkit with Gmail now?

Comment: I found an answer here https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/GMailOAuth2.md

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The deactivation of less secure applications prevents you from being able to log in directly with your *username* and *password*, but it does not prevent you from being able to generate a specific password for your application. Now, instead of logging in with your google password, you'll log in with a password that you generate for your specific app.

The solution is simple and does not require much change:

1. [Turn on 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) in your google account. This step is **required** as Google only allows generating passwords for apps on accounts that have 2-Step Verification enabled.
2. Go to generate apps password (https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) and [generate a password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB) for your app.

   [image]
3. Simply use your gmail username (`your_mail@gmail.com`) and the password generated in your `c#` application.

Comment: App password didn't work to send SMTP emails for me.

Comment: This worked, but only if I used port 465. Port 587, which is what most Google docs seem to recommend gave me an error

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the App Password option with gmail.

Dealt with this today. Just go to the gmail account, then go to Manage Your Google Account > Security.

From here enable 2-factor authentication, then once you have done You will see the "App passwords" option appear under the 2-step verification option. Click on this, name the device that you want to use, and then copy & paste the generated password that you are given into your code in place of the old password that you were using.

I've done this now for our office printer & the python script that I had to automatically deliver timesheets to everyone.